# Reducing noise from a large return register located on the door of my apartment's HVAC closet (inside)

Tags: hvac, insulation, air-conditioning, vent, ducts

My central air intake register emits a constant loud roar whenever the AC is blowing; it is so loud that it drowns out radio or human conversation going on.
I have done some reading and learned that sound mazes or baffles can work.
Since I am not a professional HVAC person or a carpenter who could build a suitable sound baffle on the inside of the door of my HVAC closet, I came up with the idea of using flexible ducting and a collar for it to fix the ducting to the inside of that closet where the large return register is located near the floor. The ducting would be affixed and sealed to the inside surface of the over-door register with cardboard and tape; any void areas would be covered with strips of insulation, the edges sealed with mastic.
Would this overheat and ruin my AC fan? Or would this be avoided by the fact that the air ducting is opening up into the much larger volume of the small closet? I am counting on the flexible tubing baffling or mazing the sound waves enough to reduce the noise that I would hear inside the living area of my apartment.

Here is an image that might clarify my question:
[image]

Comment: while you description is useful, a photo will help us

Comment: I would be more worried about messing up your refrigeration system. The components were designed for a given air flow range, changing this can cause problems such as freezing it restricted to much. You need to determine what is actually making the noise, something is vibrating, you need to figure out what.

Comment: HI Thanks, but the noise seems to be only from the flow of air, not any loose parts or other vibrations within the air duct. I am not planning to restrict the air flow except for a winding 8-ft extension through flexible ducting, which would be pointing into the full volume of the closet housing the HVAC unit in the corner of the closet. I would be covering up the register (27" x 17") on the back of the closet door, except for the area being used by the flexible ducting opening (6' diameter).

Comment: Have you listened to the HVAC unit itself? Unless there's a *very* strong air flow (which would suggest obstructions in the ventilation canals, a smaller available diameter means faster airflow), the airflow itself should not be causing deafening roars.

Comment: Reducing a 27" x 17" register down to a 6" duct is not going to do good things to your HVAC system. That's taking it from 459 sq-in down to 28.3 sq-in - a factor of over 16:1. Even though the HVAC closet is certainly not perfectly sealed, restricting the airflow like that is guaranteed to lead to trouble.

Comment: can you just remove the grate until you move?

Comment: Hi dandavis, Yes, I could do that. The grill in it is only collecting a thin layer of dust and glasswool-like fibers anyway. IF that does not quell the loud sound of rushing air, I could seal an open-ended box into it and line its inside surface with mass loaded vinyl for noise reduction. Does this seem like a workable idea? (I already have a good quality filter inserted into the main return opening (see bottom-left of above image), so the over-door register/grill doesn't seem necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than focus on the symptoms (i.e. trying to dampen the noise), I would try to figure out the **cause**.

A constant loud roar could be something vibrating far more than it's supposed to, for example because of an imbalance in fan blades (but without more than a description at this point we can only guess what's causing the sound). This could shorten the life of the unit as a whole, either because said part will wear out fast or worse, fail more abruptly and cause additional damage.

I would therefore consider getting it **serviced**. Someone experienced may both be able to quickly find the cause and get it fixed, saving you a far bigger unit replacement bill.

Comment: All of the apartment units of my apartment complex have the same roaring sound; it just sounds like air rushing through the many horizontal vent slants of the register.

Comment: I'm wondering if the sound comes from deeper in the ventilation shafts. Assuming you have access and the tools (and if it concerns a complex, permission) to temporarily remove these vent slants? It either confirms these are the cause, or rules them out and helps you get closer to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One easy fix you might try first is to get a roll or small sheet of "Mass Loaded Vinyl", a heavy vinyl material used in soundproofing cars and washing machines.

You can get some of this, glue it to the outside of the noisy duct, and see if that is enough to hush it.

Comment: There is no duct between the over-the-door register and return register of HVAC unit. There is only the volume of the closet itself. I just want to install 8-ft ducting from the over the door's register into closet. That would seem to be the same thing (to me) as ducting with a sudden increase of volume (the closet volume). I am hoping the result would only be a muting of the air flow roar, since it would be extended into the closet from its original place above the door. The flexible 8-ft ducting would be supported in such a way as to create bends that would act as sound-reducing baffling.

Comment: OK, aghast, I will try the MLV you recommend! Thanks! It certainly looks like the simplest solution. I will report back after I try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your door is creating a sound resonance box, like a amplifier.

Isolate the door from inside with some heavy insulation to dampened the resonance, leave the air vent open.